# Querying XML data with a long, multi special character, path name

Tags: soap, xquery, basex

Just getting started with XQuery using BaseX.

The XML structure that I did not create and have no control over, looks like this:

2002test.xml:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:runSearchResponse xmlns:ns2="http://externalapi.business.footprints.numarasoftware.com/">
      <return>
        <_items>
          <_containerDefinitionId>1234</_containerDefinitionId>
          <_containerDefinitionName>Service Desk</_containerDefinitionName>
          <_itemDefinitionId>2244</_itemDefinitionId>
          <_itemDefinitionName>Service Request</_itemDefinitionName>
          <_itemId>9989</_itemId>
          <_itemFields>
            <itemFields>
              <fieldName>Icon Name</fieldName>
              <fieldValue>
                <value>default_ticket.png</value>
              </fieldValue>
            </itemFields>
            <itemFields>
              <fieldName>emailCustomerUpdate</fieldName>
              <fieldValue>
                <value>false</value>
              </fieldValue>
            </itemFields>
            <itemFields>
              <fieldName>bestContactNumber_Customer</fieldName>
              <fieldValue>
                <value/>
              </fieldValue>
            </itemFields>
          </_itemFields>
        </_items>
      </return>
    </ns2:runSearchResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Doing a simple:

```
for $x in doc("2002test.xml")
return $x
```

returns my entire document as expected.

Any attempt to drill into it is not working for me however.

I've tried:

```
for $x in doc("2002test.xml")/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:runSearchResponse/return
return $x/_items/itemFields/fieldName
```

But the long path throws a "No namespace declared for 'soap:Envelope'."

So I tried declaring the path like this:

```
declare variable $m := "/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:runSearchResponse/return";
for $x in doc("2002test.xml")//$m
return $x
```

Which got me:

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:runSearchResponse/return
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:runSearchResponse/return
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:runSearchResponse/return
...
```

I tried:

```
for $x in doc("2002test.xml")/*[local-name()='soap:Envelope'][local-name()='soap:Body'][local-name()='ns2:runSearchResponse'][local-name()='return']
    
return $x
```

Which did nothing.

Very simply I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
for $x in doc("2002test.xml")
where $x/return/_items/_itemFields/itemFields/fieldValue/value="default_ticket.png"
return $x/return/_items/_itemFields/itemFields/fieldName/text()
```

resulting in:

```
Icon Name
```

Any advice?

Comment: See your favourite XQuery tutorial for e.g. `declare namespace soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";`

Comment: @JackFleeting in this case, I'd like to be able to retrieve /fieldValue/value where /fieldName = "Icon Name" for example.

Comment: @MartinHonnen okay this helped me a lot. I am actually able to query the data now. Thank you. 

I've updated my question to better reflect this, but my issue now is properly filtering results by the .../fieldValue/value property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use basic XPath expressions with a predicate e.g.

```
doc("2002test.xml")//itemFields[fieldValue/value = "default_ticket.png"]/fieldName/text()
```

If you think you need a FLOWR expression then use e.g.

```
for $field in doc("2002test.xml")//itemFields
where $field/fieldValue/value = "default_ticket.png"
return $field/fieldName/text()
```